# How to lemmatize lists of strings in a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

Every row of my df['Review'] column consists of one list of strings (eg. ["eating", "cats", "becoming"])

I'm trying to lemmatize all the lists in the Review column such that I get ["eat", "cat", become"]

My main problem is figuring out how to iterate over a list of strings and how to pass that into my function, but I cant seem to figure it out

This is my code currently:

```
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def lem(x):
    for word in range(len(x)):
        lemmatizer.lemmatize(word)

df['Review'] =  df.apply(lambda x: lem(x['Review']), axis =1)
```

This gives the following error:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Thanks

Comment: Replace all of that with `df['Review'] = df['Review'].apply( lemmatizer.lemmatize )`.

Comment: that still doesnt work. error im getting is:  unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Then you haven't shown us nearly enough information.  Nothing in this code uses a list.

Comment: im passing a list of strings. i gave the example of  ["eating", "cats", "becoming"]

Comment: Passing a list of strings to what?  That's certainly not shown here.

Answer (score 0):

you're passing an int index to the lemmatize method:

```
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

def lem(x):
    new_list = list()
    for i in range(len(x)):
        currList = x[i]
        for word in currList:
            new_word = lemmatizer.lemmatize(word)
            new_list.append(new_word)
    return new_list

x = df['Review']
new_col = df.apply(lambda x: lem(x), axis=1)
df['Review'] = new_col.values
print (df['Review'])
```

this should work--

Comment: although this gets rid of the error, it replaces all the lists in my 'Review' column with 'NoneType' instead of lematized words

Comment: thank you for the quick update! 
i tried your solution but theres an issue with the following line:  "new_list = df.apply(lambda x: lem(x), axis=1)"
the error im getting is: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: is there anymore code? also, your function doesn't return anything

Comment: I just made another edit